# Owl Persistence Individual only context to current request?

Tags: sparql, owl, rdfs

to my understanding.

an individual with some owl:ObjectProperty relates to other individual is for reasoning.

```
but if userA create "individual1 relates built-in-individual"
```

```
the userB create "individual3 relates built-in-individual"
```

that means userB can see userA's data

these individuals should exists only in each user's request for reasoning.
but user should not get individual that created by other user with his query.

how possible to do this?

Comment: don't know what you're asking nor what you're doing ... especially, I don't get what you're saying by *" userB can see userA's data"* - Moreover, if this relates to your previous question, you should start replying to comments there first and clarify things. I don't get your whole use case nor the workflow. Maybe you can start from the beginning please? You have data, ok. And now? You want to use OWL reasoning? And if so, for what specific use case?

Answer (score 0):

From your description, looks like two protégé users are editing an ontology and saving the results - and there are data one user is entering which should be private to that user.

If that's the intent, the users shouldn't edit a common ontology, they should import the common ontology and edit their own ontology. Then access and permissions can be managed outside any owl tools, simply as access rights to online resources. The users who can download the files can access the data, those who cannot download the files won't access the data.

Comment: what if ontology is behind an restapi? the server load ontology when service start, so if one user insert some individuals the other user will have same individual in ontology, i don't want them to be isolation

Comment: Then you need to clarify the question. Clearly you have something in mind about what 'for reasoning' should imply, but it's not what I understood. Reasoning in ontologies means all axioms are passed to a reasoner, so either all users see the same results or they don't.

Comment: individual should insert temporary for reasoning

Comment: i want integrate owl work with workflow like approval process,  the user's issue require at least an approver that depends on agent plays an role holds some permisson somehow. but the users is insert into ontology when the restapi request made

Comment: Scratch my comment about Protégé, I was convinced you mentioned it in the question. The problem is when you say the rest api is called - this api canake changes to the ontology but these should not be persisted until the policy evaluation has happened. The details of how to do that will depend on which api you're referring to and what libraries it uses.